# Hibernate connections are not released after lazy collection initialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

After upgrading to hibernate 4.2.4 from 3.6 database connections are not returned to pool after initialisation of lazy collection. As a result connection pool is exhausted very quickly when number of users exceeds number of connections in the pool.
Similar symptoms are described in [HHH-4808](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4808) but we haven't observed these problems in Hibernate 3.1-3.6

Relevant settings:

```
hibernate.connection.autocommit=true
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction
```

After collection is initialized there is no open transaction. So according to setting connection has to be released.

In hibernate 3.6 connection was released (through indirect call to ConnectionManager.aggresiveRelease() from OneToManyLoader).
This is very critical change for our usage scenario. Was this change intentional? Is it possible to activate old behaviour through some combination of settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We found a workaround. Does anybody see drawbacks?**

```
EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
registry.appendListeners(EventType.INIT_COLLECTION, new InitializeCollectionEventListener());

public class InitializeCollectionEventListener implements InitializeCollectionEventListener{
    DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener defaultListener;
    InitializeCollectionEventListener(){
        defaultListener = new DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener();
    }
    public void onInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent pEvent) throws HibernateException {
        defaultListener.onInitializeCollection(pEvent);
        SessionImpl si = (SessionImpl) pEvent.getSession();
        if (!si.isTransactionInProgress() && !si.isClosed() && si.isConnected() && 
                si.getConnectionReleaseMode().equals(ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION)){
            si.getTransactionCoordinator().getJdbcCoordinator().getLogicalConnection().aggressiveRelease(); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Another solution based on InitializeCollectionEventListener... so have you checked entityManager.getReference() method?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197940/hibernate-5-db-connections-are-still-not-released-idle-in-transaction-after-l/47414402#comment99401466_47414402