# Hibernate 5: db connections are still not released (idle in transaction) after lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling, lazy-initialization

In Hibernate 5 there are still big troubles with releasing database connections after initialization of lazy collection. Database connections after lazy initialization of collection are kept in "idle in transaction". So if many users work at the same time, count of open connections is increasing critically.

We use *hibernate version 5.0.12*, *java version 1.8.0_151*, *jsf 2.3*, don't use Spring (ORM).

There is reported issue for Hibernate version 3.2.7 - [HHH-4808](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4808) - still opened. The last comment from july is 3 years later after this bug was reported and still not resolved in version 5.

I think we use recommended approach lazy loading of Hibernate. Even there exists a workaround (any drawback?) for version 4.2: [Hibernate connections are not released after lazy collection initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140609/hibernate-connections-are-not-released-after-lazy-collection-initialization). Method
     `.getJdbcCoordinator().getLogicalConnection().aggressiveRelease()` from this workaround was removed in version 5.

I think a large number of developers have to use this lazy loading of very popular Hibernate, so I don't understand, why this issue is not resolved. So are there any solutions or verified workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I can't believe this hasn't been fixed. Accessing collections through getters is a pretty important feature. Anyways, I was playing with the original workaround for 4.2 and found something that works for version 5. Try the following. It seems to work, but I have no idea what hidden side effects it may have.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CollectionEventListener extends DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener
{
   public void onInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent pEvent) throws HibernateException
   {
      super.onInitializeCollection(pEvent);
      SessionImpl si = (SessionImpl) pEvent.getSession();
      if (!si.isTransactionInProgress() && !si.isClosed() && si.isConnected()
         && si.getJdbcCoordinator().getLogicalConnection().getConnectionHandlingMode()
           .getReleaseMode().equals(ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION))
      {
         si.getJdbcCoordinator().afterTransaction();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Keith, now we are using a very similar solution (see my answer). It´s working fine for all our tests, so we have decided use this solution in our project.

Comment: Pls, do you use this solution in your project? I'm asking, because this (and my too) solution works only for collections with binding 'ManyToMany', but for "easier" 'ManyToOne' binding we have the same trouble with the connection "idle in transaction". Am I missing something? Do we have to overriden one more listener for loading 'ManyToOne' binding?

Comment: I do use this solution in my project. I have ManyToMany, ManyToOne, OneToMany, and even OneToOne relationships. Since I started using this solution, I haven't noticed any connections that were stuck "idle in transaction". It's possible the way you and I are using the entities and managing the transactions is different enough that I don't run into that case.

Comment: Hmm, I'm glad, that this solution is working for you. We try to use this lazy loading approach of hibernate in web jsf (2.3) project. When user requested view is created we open new hibernate session. In this hibernate session we are loading/working with data from database and right here is our problem with connections stuck in "idle in transaction". When we are loading an object with ManyToOne relationship, connection is keeping "idle in transaction". After user has changed entire view we will close the session. I think we use "standard" approach or is there something bad?

Comment: I suspect that this solution only covers the LAZY Collections problem, but does not cover the entityManager.getReference () method. Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

The same as [FoxyBOA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218601/3596127) and [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47402831/3596127) we are fiddling 
with a workaround how to close connection after lazy initialization of collection (for Hibernate version 5.) and there is our similar solution:

```
public class MyInitializeCollectionEventListener implements InitializeCollectionEventListener {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener defaultListener;

   @Override
   public void onInitializeCollection(InitializeCollectionEvent initializeCollectionEvent) throws HibernateException {
    defaultListener.onInitializeCollection(initializeCollectionEvent);
    SessionImpl si = (SessionImpl) initializeCollectionEvent.getSession();
    if (!si.isTransactionInProgress() &&
        !si.isClosed() &&
         si.isConnected() && 
         si.getJdbcCoordinator().getConnectionReleaseMode().equals(ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION)){

        si.getJdbcCoordinator().getLogicalConnection().afterTransaction();
    }
}
```

It's working for all our tests, but if there are any drawbacks, I really don't know...

Comment: Your solution and mine probably function the same. Instead of having an instance of DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener, mine just extends that class and calls super.onInitializeCollection(). My solution replaces the deprecated getConnectionReleaseMode() with getLogicalConnection().getConnectionHandlingMode().getReleaseMode().The last difference is mine calls afterTransaction() on the JdbcCoordinator whereas you skip that and call it directly on LogicalConnection. I didn't skip JdbcCoordinator because it sets transactionTimeOutInstant to -1. I believe both solutions work.

Comment: It might even be possible that we don't need DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener at all.

Comment: Same comment than for @Keith, have you checked entityManager.getReference() method? It's not a load event fired for a lazy collection, and this listener sounds to be used for Collections only.